# h:selectOneListBox not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, mojarra

I have a simple JSF application with a form, one of the controls being a `selectOneListbox`:

```
<h:selectOneListbox style="width: 231px; height: 27px;position:absolute;left:400px;top:325px;" value="#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{PatientsSearch.doctors}" var="d" itemLabel="#{d.name}" itemValue="#{d.name}" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

When I run the application, I can see the list being populated (i.e. PatientsSearch.doctors is correctly retrieved), so I can choose one item from the `selectOneListbox`. After I choose the desired item, nothing works any more on that form. All the other buttons seem to be idle, they don't react to clicks any more. If however nothing is selected from the `selectOneListbox`, all buttons works as expected (i.e. they trigger their callbacks in the managed beans).

I debugged the application and noticed that indeed, after selecting an item in the list, the callbacks of the other buttons on the form don't get triggered when clicking them.
Also in the debugger I never see *setSelectedDoctor()* being called (see the snippet above) as I expected.

I'm using Mojarra 2.0.1 implementation of JSF.

What am I missing here ?

---

**Update:** This is the entire form:

```
    <h:form style="width: 876px; background-color: #FED981; padding-left: 60px; padding-top: 30px; margin-left: 80px; margin-top: 40px; color: #804000; font-style: normal; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif">
    <h:outputLabel style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:100px;" value="New appointment:"></h:outputLabel>
    <br>
    <br>
    <h:inputText style="width: 259px;position:absolute;left:200px;top:120px;" binding="#{PatientsSearch.inputText1}" valueChangeListener="#{PatientsSearch.lookForName}" immediate="true" id="inputText1" />
    <h:commandButton value ="Search patients by name:" style="width: 173px;position:absolute;left:465px;top:120px;" action="#{PatientsSearch.getPatientsByName}">
        <f:param name="day" value="#{request.getParameter('day')}" />
        <f:param name="month" value="#{request.getParameter('month')}" />
        <f:param name="year" value="#{request.getParameter('year')}" />  
    </h:commandButton>

    <br>
    <h:panelGroup id="pn_DETAILS_GRP" style="overflow:auto;position:absolute;top:155px;left:200px;width:300px;height:150px;solid black">
        <h:dataTable id="tb_USER_DETAILS" border="1" var="patient" value="#{PatientsSearch.patients}" style="width:300px;height:150px" rowClasses="oddRow, evenRow">
        <h:column id="name">
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Name" style="font-size:10pt"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patient.name}" style="font-size:8pt"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column id="phone">
        <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Phone" style="font-size:10pt"/>
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{patient.phoneMobile}" style="font-size:8pt"/>
        </h:column>
        <h:column>
        <h:inputHidden id="patientId" value="#{patient.id}" />
        </h:column>
        </h:dataTable>
    </h:panelGroup>

    <h:inputHidden id="testId"  />

    <br><br><br>
    <h:outputLabel value="Choose doctor:" style="width: 200px;position:absolute;left:200px;top:325px;"></h:outputLabel>
    <h:selectOneListbox style="width: 231px; height: 27px;position:absolute;left:400px;top:325px;" value="#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}" size="1">
        <f:selectItems value="#{PatientsSearch.doctors}" var="d"
            itemLabel="#{d.name}" itemValue="#{d.name}" />
    </h:selectOneListbox>
    <br><br><br>
    <h:commandButton value="Schedule" style="position:absolute;left:200px;top:430px;" action="#{PatientsSearch.scheduleAppointment}">
        <f:param name="day" value="#{request.getParameter('day')}" />
        <f:param name="month" value="#{request.getParameter('month')}" />
        <f:param name="year" value="#{request.getParameter('year')}" /> 
    </h:commandButton>

</h:form>
```

Comment: You should add some other parts of your form, including the button. At first sight it could be a convertion of validation error, have you an `h:messages` somewhere?

Comment: There is no button in this form? _All the other buttons seem to be idle, they don't react to clicks any more._ which ones? What are the getters/setters for `#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}` and `#{d.name}` ?

Comment: Hi, you can see the whole form - I've added it above. There are two buttons and they work fine only if I don't select any item in the selectOneListbox. Otherwise their callbacks are not triggered.

Comment: Both buttons will send the all form, is that what you want? I suspect a convertion error when you select doctor, are `#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}` and `#{d.name}` Strings ?

Comment: d.name is a String, PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor is a Doctor type. So the issue is most likely about the latter. I'll make it a String and check. This is what you suspect the issue is, right ?

Comment: You need to change itemValue="#{d.name}" for itemValue="#{d}"

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, what you say makes perfect sense, but it seems more complex than that. If I use itemValue="#{d}", then it is even worse than before: the other buttons are not working even for the first time. The alternative is to make everything Strings (i.e. "selectedDoctor") and then the buttons seem to work, but the selection looks strange - all Doctor objects seem serialized and concatenated, and this is what I get in my "selectedDoctor" variable. It looks as if all doctors from the list are selected at the same time.This is totally crazy, I believe I'll drop this stupid selectOneListbox

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, the problem is that the type for `#{d.name}` is not the same as `#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}`. In such situation there is two solutions :

1. Keep everything you have the same, change the `#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}` getter/setter to a String type.
2. Create a list of `SelectItem` in the backing bean and change the `#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}` getter/setter to a String type. You will also be able to remove `itemValue` and `itemLabel` since the backing bean already provide ready Object for list components.
3. Change the `itemValue` attribute from the `f:selectItems` and create a custom converter

I prefer the second since it separate better the view. It should be changed like this :

```
<h:selectOneListbox style="width: 231px; height: 27px;position:absolute;left:400px;top:325px;" value="#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}" size="1">
    <f:selectItems value="#{PatientsSearch.doctors}" var="d" itemLabel="#{d.name}" />
    <f:converter convertId="doctorConverter" />
</h:selectOneListbox>
```

Now for the converter, you can start it like this :

```
@FacesConverter(value="doctorConverter")
public class DoctorConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        // Your code, select doctor from value ID for example.
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        // Your code, return doctor ID from value.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexandre, what you say makes perfect sense, but it seems more complex than that. If I use itemValue="#{d}", then it is even worse than before: the other buttons are not working even for the first time. The alternative is to make everything Strings (i.e. "selectedDoctor") and then the buttons seem to work, but the selection looks strange - all Doctor objects seem serialized and concatenated, and this is what I get in my "selectedDoctor" variable. It looks as if all doctors from the list are selected at the same time.This is totally crazy, I believe I'll drop this stupid selectOneListbox

Comment: @Sorin-AlexandruCristescu Unfortunately I was putting you in the wrong direction, you actually need a converter as modified answer.

Comment: Right, I expected I could do this without a converter. But it's ok like this too, I'll give it a try, it has to work .... Thanks a lot. Any idea why the String wasn't working (as I explained) ? I shouldn't need a converter for that.

Comment: @Sorin-AlexandruCristescu it really depend on how you want to handle the data selected, if you only need the name for example, you can keep the `itemValue="#{d.name}"` and just change the `#{PatientsSearch.selectedDoctor}` to String type. But I don't think this is good. The only thing the converter does, is giving you back your Object which is a good think so you do the converter once and whatever you need from the Object, you never get stuck.

Comment: Sure, I got your point. However, the first part (using d.name and having selectedDoctor as a String) doesn't work: when I select something from the selectOneListbox, selectedDoctor is set to the whole list of doctors is a String-serialized form (not just the name I selected). This is totally crazy, I have no idea why is that.

Comment: @Sorin-AlexandruCristescu Just tested on my side and it is working properly (String type selection value). Are you sure that your `#{d.name}` return the good value? Normally you only have to change the selection property (to String). I've edited the answer to be more clear and moved 1 to 2 and created a new 1 that is what you are trying.

Comment: What worries me is that when I actually select an item from the selectOneListbox, there's **no call to the PatientsSearch's setSelectedDoctor**, as one would expect. How can that be ? Do I need to add a specific handler for when the item changes ? I expected the selectOneListbox to work out of the box. Could there be other errors on the page ? What's the easiest way to check ?

Comment: @Sorin-AlexandruCristescu Yes I suspect other errors on the page if it doesn't work. Try to add a `h:messages` to your page, in your case you don't use AJAX so it will update and you will see if you have convertion or validation errors. You can also try to remove temporary things from your form.